# What can cause the volume keys to not work but show the prohibitory sign instead of changing volume?

Tags: macos, audio

When i try to reduce my mac book volume it suddenly shows that this isn't possible, even the icon in the menu bar is (grey inactive)

This happens sometimes since i installed lion os

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I have experienced this issue starting with my new install of Lion. I haven't been able to find the cause of the issue but I do have a quick way to reset the audio system and get back volume control.

Open Activity Monitor (Its in Applications/Utilities)

Make sure it is set to All Processes, look for coreaudiod, click "Quit Process" then "Quit". Wait a few seconds and you should have volume control back.

If your a terminal buff a quick `sudo killall coreaudiod` should whip it into shape.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to check is the selected output device in System Preferences. To do that, open System Preferences and click on "Sound".

[image]

Next, go through each of the tabs to verify that you don't see any obvious settings. I've seen this before on Snow Leopard, and although I'm now on Lion, I don't think this changed much.

[image]

I don't remember what the setting were, but it was fairly obvious to me what to change.

Comment: For me it was trying to output over DisplayPort to my monitor that doesn't have speakers.  I switched to Internal Speakers and it worked.

Comment: This effectively fixed the issue for me. Just like what stephen mentioned in the above, my Mac was also trying to output to my monitor

Answer (score 3):

Check inside the headphone jack. Is a red light showing? If so, the MacBook might be trying to output optical audio. Make sure nothing is stuck in there - lint, dust, etc. Plugging in and then removing headphones may also help. If the red light stays, best to bring it in for service.

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested, I cHecked inside the headphone jack and found a red light showing.   Plugging in and then removing headphones solved the problem.  Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

When I had to use Force Quit to close a stuck Premier Elements 9, it somehow reset the audio. Go to System Preferences → Sound → Output and re-choose Internal Speakers to get the sound going again, as well as the buttons on the keyboard to control the speakers.

Answer (score 0):

I personally tried most of the listed above. What I ended up doing before I did anything too crazy (i'm not super techy) is I just put in my earbuds again and took them out. I didn't have a read light going near the headphone jack, but it did the job. Now I have control again! I hope that helps you, my friends!