# Volume control (sliders or keys) stops working after plugging into/out of headphone jack

Tags: macos, audio

I plug my machine into a projector/sound amplification setup regularly for teaching.  Often, when I get back home afterwards, the sound volume controls no longer work.  Neither the dedicated volume keys in the function key row, nor the volume slider in the menu bar have any affect on output volume.  Also, the keys changes don't affect the slider position, or vice versa.

I've done some searching and testing and the only working solution I've found is to reboot. Not a great solution. I've tried switching output devices (no change) and restarting coreaudio (no change). I'm on 10.6.8.

Any non-reboot suggestions?

Comment: Related questions: [Output volume control isn't working](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38230/output-volume-control-isnt-working?rq=1), [What can cause the volume keys to not work but show the prohibitory sign instead of changing volume?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19094/what-can-cause-the-volume-keys-to-not-work-but-show-the-prohibitory-sign-instead?rq=1)

Comment: mine never shows the prohibitory sign. it acts like it's changing the volume as requested, but those changes have no aural effect.

Comment: Can you change the volume in System Preferences?

Comment: If you take a look at your *System Preferences < Sound*, what do you see on "output"? I think the projector will be listed there and you Mac is still thinking you're connected to the projector.

Comment: @Lri yes i can change the volume successfully in the sound pref panel, although changes in the slider there do not affect the slider in the menu bar, and after adjusting vol there the keys still don't work

Comment: @Michiel it's set as 'internal speakers'.  no projector listed.

Comment: And if you reboot your Mac, everything works just fine?

Comment: right, a reboot fixes it

Comment: Are you running WINE/X11 by any chance? Or have you tried to kill coreaudiod (`sudo killall coreaudiod`) in stead of rebooting it? According to Apple, it has something to do with your projector not compatible with the Mac OS...

Comment: not running wine.  haven't run x11 in a long time.  have tried the `sudo killall coreaudiod` without effect.

Comment: Are you running any third party audio software? Sound Flower is pretty invasive and can be installed by Audio Hijack Pro. Have you tried logging out and back in?

Comment: ok, good question.  I do have soundflower installed.  pretty sure i installed it manually at some point.  for that matter I also have the logmeinsounddriver installed.  I'll uninstall those and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

According to this thread, holding down any of the volume keys as you plug or unplug the audio jack will solve this problem. It's a known issue.

See this thread: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1254855

Comment: This does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

I have had that problem with my Mac book. The sound was not working after plugging my computer in a pa system. After an hour of searching I found the solution. Plug in your headphone into the port your sound slider should work and you have sound coming through your headphone, reboot your computer keeping your headphone plugin and remove/unplug your headphone your sound slider should work again. The Mac helpline didn't provide a solution except your Mac needs to be serviced! Hope it helps.

Comment: This solution is absurd. Each time we use headphones we're supposed to reboot? lol I thought Apple machines were about ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

I came in with the same problem, but I think I found the solution... I plugged my macbook to a projector for teaching and encountered the same problem. I'm sharing what I did, worked for me, hope to work for you too..

go to **System Preferences>Sound>Output**

there in the window, the projector output must be highlighted with blue... select the option **"headphone"** to enable it while your headphone is plugged in. Its just that the projector audio option had been enabled in your mac. Now check your audio through headphones...

I hope this cleared your confusion. Just let me know...
happy macbooking :) :) :)

Comment: also doesn't work